Application of fix point theorem for functions $\epsilon,\delta:[0,1]\to[0,1]$
I have two functions $\epsilon,\delta:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ such that the following hold for all $x,y\in[0,1]$:
$$
\text{(i) $x+\epsilon(x)\in[0,1]$ and $x-\delta(x)\in[0,1]$}
$$
$$
\text{(ii) if $y\in [x,x+\epsilon(x)]$ then $\epsilon(y)\geq x-y + \epsilon(x)$}
$$
$$
\text{(iii) if $y\in [x-\delta(x),x]$ then $\delta(y)\geq y-x+\delta(x)$}
$$
$$
\text{(iv) $\delta(x+\epsilon(x))\geq \epsilon(x) $}
$$
$$
\text{(v) $\epsilon(x-\delta(x))\geq \delta(x) $}
$$
My intuition tells me that one can use fixpoint theorems to derive properties of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$. Especially I am guessing that they are monotone functions. Also I think it could hold that $\epsilon(x)=\delta(1-x)$. But I don't know how to prove any of this unfortunately. Maybe someone knows how to do it. Anything that can be said about $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ would be helpful.

I will show: If $\epsilon,\delta$ are monotone and analytic in some
domain containing $[0,1],$ then $\epsilon(x)=1-x$ and $\delta(x)=x.$
The monotonicity and analyticity assumptions will be introduced when
they are needed.
Let $f(x):=x+\epsilon(x)$ and $g(x):=x-\delta(x).$ The first lemma
gives statements equivalent to (i)-(v) in terms involving $f,g.$
For ease of reference I included $\epsilon,\delta:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$
in the lemma.
Lemma 1. 
We have
0). $\epsilon,\delta:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$
1). $f,g:[0,1]\to[0,1].$
2). $f$ is increasing, that is $0\leq x<y\leq1\implies f(x)\leq f(y).$
3). $g$ is increasing, that is $0\leq x<y\leq1\implies g(x)\leq g(y).$
4). For all $x\in[0,1],$ $\delta(f(x))\geq\epsilon(x).$
5). For all $x\in[0,1],$ $\epsilon(g(x))\geq\delta(x).$

Proof:
Proof of 1). By definition of $f,g$ this is equivalent to (i).
Proof of 2). Suppose $0\leq x<y\leq1.$ If $y\leq f(x),$ then (ii)
yields $\epsilon(y)\ge x-y+\epsilon(x)$, that is $f(x)\leq f(y).$
If $f(x)\leq y,$ then $\epsilon(y)\geq0$ tells us $y\leq f(y).$
Thus $f(x)\leq y\leq f(y).$
Proof of 3). Suppose $0\leq x<y\leq1.$ If $g(y)\leq x,$ then (iii)
yields $\delta(x)\geq x-y+\delta(y),$ that is $g(y)\ge g(x).$ If
$x\leq g(y),$ then $\delta(x)\geq0$ tells us $g(x)\leq x.$ Thus
$g(x)\leq x\leq g(y).$
Proof of 4). This is (iv) and the definition of $f.$
Proof of 5). This is (v) and the definition of $g.$
 ∎ 
Corollary 2. 
6). $\epsilon(1)=0,f(1)=1,$ and
7). $\delta(0)=0,g(0)=0.$

Proof:
This follows from the definitions of $f$ and $g$ and 0) and 1).
In fact, $1\leq1+\epsilon(1)=f(1)\leq1,$ so $\epsilon(1)=0$ and
$f(1)=1.$ Similarly, $0\leq g(0)=0-\delta(0)\leq0,$ so $\delta(0)=0$
and $g(0)=0.$
 ∎ 
Corollary 3. 
For any $x\in[0,1],$
8). $\delta(f(g(x)))\geq\delta(x)$ and
9). $\epsilon(g(f(x)))\geq\epsilon(x).$

Proof:
By 4) and 5) $\delta(f(g(x)))\geq\epsilon(g(x))\geq\delta(x)$ and
$\epsilon(g(f(x)))\geq\delta(f(x))\geq\epsilon(x)$
 ∎ 
Theorem 4. 
The following statements are equivalent:
$f$ is constant,
$g$ is constant,
$f(x)=1,$ for all $x\in[0,1],$
$g(x)=0,$ for all $x\in[0,1],$
$\epsilon(x)=1-x,$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ and
$\delta(x)=x$ for all $x\in[0,1].$

Proof:
If $f$ is constant, then by 6) we have $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in[0,1]$
and the definition of $f$ gives $\epsilon(x)=1-x$ for all $x\in[0,1].$
Hence, by 9), $1-g(1)\geq1-x$ for all $x.$ That is, $x\geq g(1)$
for all $x.$ In particular, $g(1)=0.$ Hence, by 3), $g(x)=0$ for
all $x,$ so $\delta(x)=x$ for all $x.$
If $g$ is constant, then by 7) we have $g(x)=0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$
and the definition of $g$ gives $\delta(x)=x$ for all $x\in[0,1].$
Hence, by 8), $f(0)\geq x$ for all $x.$ Setting $x=1$ gives, $f(0)=1.$
Hence, by 2), $f(x)=1$ for all $x,$ so $\epsilon(x)=1-x$ for all
$x.$
The remaining cases are trivial.
 ∎ 
For the remainder of this solution assume:
 (A)  $f$ is not constant. Then the negations of all the statements
in Theorem 4 are true. In particular, $g$ is not constant.
and
 (B)  $\epsilon,\delta$ are monotone. Then $\epsilon$ is decreasing
(since $\epsilon(1)=0$) and $\delta$ is increasing (since $\delta(0)=0$).
Lemma 5. 
$f(g(1))=1$ and $g(f(0))=0.$

Proof:
By 8) $\delta(f(g(1)))\geq\delta(1)$. By (B) $\delta(x)=\delta(1)$
for $f(g(1))\leq x\leq1$. If $f(g(1))<1,$ then by (iii) $0=\delta(y)-\delta(x)\geq y-x>0$
for $f(g(1))\leq x<y\leq1$. Consequently, $f(g(1))=1.$
By 7) $\epsilon(g(f(0)))\geq\epsilon(0).$ By (B) $\epsilon(x)=\epsilon(0)$
for $0\leq x\leq g(f(0)).$ If $0<g(f(0))$, then by (ii) $0=\epsilon(y)-\epsilon(x)\geq x-y>0$
for $0\leq y<x\leq g(f(0))$. Consequently, $g(f(0))=0.$
 ∎ 
Lemma 6. 
Suppose $\epsilon,\delta$ are analytic on some domain containing
$[0,1].$ Then $f(0)=0$ and $g(1)=1.$ Additionally, $\epsilon(0)=1$
and $\delta(1)=1.$

Proof:
If $g(1)<1,$ then $f$ is constant on $[g(1),1],$ by Lemma 5 and
2). Hence, $f$ is constant. Contradicting (A).
If $0<f(0),$ then $g$ is constant on $[0,f(0)],$ by Lemma 5 and
3). Hence, $g$ is constant. Contradicting (A).
 ∎ 
Lemma 7. 
Suppose $\epsilon,\delta$ are analytic on some domain containing
$[0,1].$ Then $\epsilon(x)=1-x$ and $\delta(x)=x$ for all $x\in[0,1].$

Proof:
Fix $x\in[0,1].$ The conclusions holds at $x=0,1.$ So we may assume
$0<x<1.$
By 2) $f'\geq0.$ So $1+\epsilon'\geq0.$ Hence,
$$
0\leq\int_{0}^{x}1+\epsilon'=x+\epsilon(x)-\epsilon(0).
$$
Using $\epsilon(0)=1$ we get $1-x\leq\epsilon(x).$ Similarly,
$$
0\leq\int_{x}^{1}1+\epsilon'=1-x+\epsilon(1)-\epsilon(x).
$$
Using $\epsilon(1)=0,$ we get $\epsilon(x)\leq1-x.$ Thus $\epsilon(x)=1-x.$
The proof for $\delta$ is similar, but we do not need this claim
below.
 ∎ 
By Theorem 4, the conclusion of Lemma 7 contradicts (A). Hence our
assumptions (A), (B), and analyticity leads to a contradiction,
thus one of them must fail.
